# Is it possible to get device phone number by imei number in android

Tags: java, android, phone-number, telephonymanager, imei

I like to know its possible by enter `IMEI` number can my app detect users current device phone number.

Comment: I'm not sure that the device or SIM card contain own phone number (like +1 123456...).

Comment: ya,  you are right but how do facebook reads my current phone number when ever i login with new device its  suggestion current using number with pre-filled. do you have any idea how this happens

Comment: I believe that Facebook uses your own contact from device's contact list.

Answer (score -2):

May be you can use this code to get the phone number.

Code:

```
TelephonyManager phneMgr = (TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String phneNmbr = phneMgr.getLine1Number();
```

Required Permission

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: above code doesn't working with all devices so i looking is there possibility to get phone number through IMEI number.